# Get Substring of value when using import-Csv in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a PowerShell script that imports a CSV file, filters out rows from two columns and then concatenates a string and exports to a new CSV file.

```
Import-Csv "redirect_and_canonical_chains.csv" |
Where { $_."Number of Redirects" -gt 1} |
Select {"Redirect 301 ",$_.Address, $_."Final Address"} |
Export-Csv "testing-export.csv" –NoTypeInformation
```

This all works fine however for the $_.Address value I want to strip the domain, sub-domain and protocol etc using the following regex

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)
```

This individually works and matches as I want but I am not sure of the best way to implement when selecting the data (should I use $match, -replace etc) or whether I should do it after importing?

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Mike

Comment: You can use a [calculated property](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) in your `select` to do this.

Comment: Hi James, many thanks for the reply and link. Would you be able to give me an example of how I would implement this in my script above for the scenario described. I'm not quite clear on the syntax to use from the linked page.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The best place to do it would be in the select clause, as in:

```
select Property1,Property2,@{name='NewProperty';expression={$_.Property3 -replace '<regex>',''}}
```

That's what a calculated property is: you give the name, and the way to create it.Your regex might need revision to work with PowerShell, though.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! Is there are any problem with doing the replace in the way I have done. It appears to have the expected result in the CSV output

Comment: If it works, keep it, I don't foresee any problem. That being said, select normally takes a list of properties, and you feed it a scriptblock. Honestly, I don't even understand why it works! :D

Comment: Hmm, it works ok with static values but the regex isn't picking up matches (although it works in regexr). Is there anything in particular that I need to watch out for with using regex in PowerShell?

Comment: Did you try the PCRE flavour? That's much closer to .Net implementation than javascript (I use Regex101 myself, but PCRE is PCRE).

Comment: So, I tried, and it seems to be that your domain name is included in the regex. So either you have to get it in the replace string: `-replace '^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)','$1'`, or simply remove it from the regex: `-replace '^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?',''`

Answer (score 0):

I've realized now that I can just use .Replace in the following way :)

```
Select {"Redirect 301 ",$_.Address.Replace('http://', 'testing'), $_."Final Address"}
```

Comment: This creates objects with a single property literally named `"Redirect 301 ",$_.Address.Replace('http://', 'testing'), $_."Final Address"` whose value is a 3-element array. Given that this won't meaningfully serialize to a CSV file with `Export-Csv`, I'm assuming it's not what you actually need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just need to generate a single string for each for each row which seems to what's happening so that is ok. Each row should contain something like

301 redirect /oldurl.html mydomain.com/new-url.html

The purpose of the regex rule is to strip out the domain part. If I test the rule on a static string then it works fine but it doesn't work on the select statement

Select {"Redirect 301 ",($_.Address).Replace($regEx,''), $_.'Final Address'}|

Comment: `.Replace()` performs literal substring replacement - it doesn't with regexes. If you just want to return a string, don't use `Select` - use `ForEach-Object` (`%`) with a script block that outputs the desired string. You're looking for something like `... | % { '{0} {1} {2}' -f 'Redirect 301', ($_.Address -replace '^http://[^/]+'), $_.'Final Address' }`

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks again. I have changed to using ForEach-Object but still the same result. Maybe I am not understanding correctly. Could you tell me what is wrong here?

    ForEach-Object{ Write-Host "Redirect 301 ", ($_.Address -replace 
    '^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)}', ''), $_.'Final Address'}

Comment: Just realised I had a } at the end in the wrong place and when removed it works! thanks so much again @mklement0

Comment: My pleasure, but  `Write-Host` is not the right cmdlet to use for outputting data - please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on follow-up comments, the intent behind your `Select[-Object]` call was to create a *single string* with space-separated entries from each input object.

Note that use of `Export-Csv` then makes no sense, because it will create a single `Length` column with the input strings' *length* rather than output the strings themselves.

In a follow-up comment you posted a solution that used `Write-Host` to produce the output string, but  [`Write-Host` is generally the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is explicitly to write *to the display only*, thereby bypassing PowerShell's output streams and thus the ability to send the output to other commands, capture it in a variable or redirect it to a file.

Here's a fixed version of your command, which uses the `-join` operator to join the elements of a string array to output a single, space-separated string:

```
$sampleCsvInput = [pscustomobject] @{ 
  Address = 'http://www.example.org/more/stuff'; 
  'Final Address' = 'more/stuff2'
}

$sampleCsvInput | ForEach-Object { 
  "Redirect 301 ", 
  ($_.Address -replace '^(?:https?://)?(?:[^@/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:/\n]+)', ''), 
  $_.'Final Address' -join ' ' 
}
```

<sup>Note that `,` - PowerShell's array-construction operator - has higher precedence than the `-join` operator, so the `-join` operation indeed joins all 3 preceding array elements.</sup>

The above yields the following string:

```
Redirect 301  /more/stuff more/stuff2
```